# How can I use a Local SQLite3 DB for Testing and a MSSQL DB for Production in Django?

Tags: sql-server, django

So I have a project I'm currently working on where my DB user does not have the ability to create and destroy databases on the server where my production DB is stored.  So I have decided to try and locate my test databases within sqlite3 database much like is shipped with Django. I tried doing this which I think I read about somewhere in the Django documentation, but it is not working and keeps giving me the error:

> AttributeError: 'PosixPath' object has no attribute 'startswith'

Code:

```
DATABASES = {
    # C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'engine',
        'NAME': 'db',
        'HOST': '1.1.1.1',
        'PORT': '1',
        'USER': 'username',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'driver': 'driver',
            'connection_timeout': 15
        },
        'TEST': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
            'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'testdb.sqlite3',
            'HOST': 'localhost'
        }
    },
}
```

I feel like I'm close and so I tried removing the BASE_DIR and just going with the file name but that still sends me messages saying that the user does not have the ability to create DB in master which means it's still connecting to the same PRODUCTION server.

Answer (score 0):

The best option is to use always the same db for testing and for production to have continuity with it.

You can consider to create manually the database and use the --keepdb option to avoid creare/destroy the database at ever test run.

```
python manage.py test --keepdb
```

Other than having that config, you should also create a database routing to route the requests to the rigth DB.

EDIT:
if you want to have multiple db on different hosts, the base_dir is not required. Plus the db name should be at the same level as the default one:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'mydb',
        'USER': 'user',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': 'server1',
        'PORT': '1111'
    },
    'test': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': 'mydb',
        'USER': 'user',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': 'server2',
        'PORT': '1111'
    }
}
```

Then in your test, you can write something like this:

```
class MyTestCases(TestCase):
    databases = {'test'}

    def test_other_db_query(self):
        pass
```

More info about how to use another db for testing purposes:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/testing/tools/#testing-multi-db

Comment: I want my test DB located on a different server is this possible?

Comment: reply updated for multiple DB and multiple DB type and hosts